# case label value exceeds maximum value for type c++

Tags: c++, types

I'm having trouble with all the switches that I've made in this text, my question is what do I need to write, so that this problem doesn't occur? Which type should I wright?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void tablero (int i, int j);
char matriz [3][3];
int comprueba ();
void jugador1 ();
void jugador2 ();



int main (){
int comp,i,j;
cout<<"Bienvenido al 3 en ralla!"<<endl;
cout<<" -----------------------"<<endl;

for (i=0;i<=2; i++){
    for(j=0;j<=2; j++){
        matriz [i][j]='-';
    }
}
do{
    jugador1();

    jugador2();

}
while(comp==0);

cout<<"GRACIAS POR JUGAR <3!";
return 0;
}

void tablero (int i,int j)
{
 cout << matriz[0][0] << " | " << matriz[0][1] << " | " << matriz[0][2] <<endl;
 cout << matriz[1][0] << " | " << matriz[1][1] << " | " << matriz[1][2] <<endl;
 cout << matriz[2][0] << " | " << matriz[2][1] << " | " << matriz[2][2] <<endl;

return;
}

int comprueba (){
  int comp;

    switch (matriz[0][0]==matriz[0][1]==matriz[0][2]){  //horizontal 1
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }

       switch (matriz[1][0]==matriz[1][1]==matriz[1][2]){  //horizontal 2
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }

        switch (matriz[2][0]==matriz[2][1]==matriz[2][2]){  //horizontal 3
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }

       switch (matriz[0][0]==matriz[1][0]==matriz[2][0]){  //vertical 1
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }
       switch (matriz[0][1]==matriz[1][1]==matriz[2][1]){  //vertical 2
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }
       switch (matriz[0][2]==matriz[1][2]==matriz[2][2]){  //vertical 3
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }

       switch (matriz[0][0]==matriz[1][1]==matriz[2][2]){  //oblícua 1
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }

       switch (matriz[0][2]==matriz[1][1]==matriz[2][0]){  //oblícua 2
        case 'X':
            cout<<"Jugador 1 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        case 'O':
            cout<<"Jugador 2 es el ganador! Enhorabuena!"<<endl;
            comp=1;
            break;
        default:
            comp=0;
       }

return comp;
}

void jugador1 (void){
int i, j;
cout<<"Jugador 1, introduce una posicion"<<endl<<"Fila:";
cin>>i;
cout<<endl<<"Columna:"<<endl;
cin>>j;
i=i-1;
j=j-1;

if (i>3 || j>3){
    cout<<"Esta cordenada no existe, introduce otra jugador 1";
}
else{
    matriz [i][j]='X';

    tablero(i,j);

}

comprueba ();
return ;
}

void jugador2 (void){
int i, j;
cout<<"Jugador 2, introduce una posicion"<<endl<<"Fila:";
cin>>i;
cout<<endl<<"Columna:"<<endl;
cin>>j;
i=i-1;
j=j-1;

if (i>3 || j>3){
    cout<<"Esta cordenada no existe, introduce otra jugador 2";
}
else{
    matriz [i][j]='O';

    tablero(i,j);

}

comprueba ();   
return ;
}
```

Thank you everyone that has reached here, if you have any idea on how to do all off this please explain it to and ill will apreceate it much <3!!

Comment: You are switching on `bool`, so `case 'X'` doesn't make sense.

Comment: try a bunch of if/else for this. Switch cases are usually a constant. But since you are doing computations and ending up with a bool, there's no legal way to convert that bool to a character and then check it against a bunch of other characters.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that defining a variable with the same name in two different functions make them the same variable. That's not true. Please learn about scoping and life-time of variables. In fact, this problem leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as it leads you to use uninitialized variables with *indeterminate* values.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: For your next questions on SO, put some efforts into making your code entirely readable by English speaking persons (and that includes naming variables and functions with "English-looking" identifiers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `matriz[1][0]==matriz[1][1]==matriz[1][2]` don't do what you dream about. Since it is a `==` test it evaluates to a `bool` (and the second `==` would compare a `bool` -the result of `matriz[1][0]==matriz[1][1]`- with a `char` -the value of `matriz[1][2]`-; there is no implied conjunction like you want it to happen). You need to read more about [C++ operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) and their [precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) (notably of [comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)).

Then a `bool` can never be equal to `'X'`. It can be `true` or `false` (and even when that is converted to a `char`, it will never be `'X'`; on most systems, `(char)false` is the <kbd>NUL</kbd> character; with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) used on nearly every computer, `(char)true` is the `\001` *start-of-heading* [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) and you probably don't need that.

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. If using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve your code to get no warnings.

Then read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

My recommendation: stop coding during a few days, and spend them **reading more**. Read first a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book (in full). Look into some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site. Study how to [use your compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). Learn to [use your debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), and a tiny bit of some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (like [git](https://git-scm.com/), which has excellent tutorial videos; you just want to learn a tiny bit of `git`). Then come back to your program (you'll better scrap it entirely and write again your code, when you have learnt the basics; you'll probably write a few dozen lines, *debug* them, and improve your code with another few dozen lines, debug it again, and repeat till satisfied; following an [iterative and incremental development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) approach.).

BTW, it could help to study the source code of some *existing* small [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) or in a Linux distribution). That might be inspirational.

PS. Even if that takes you more than an hour, following all the hyperlinks here will be helpful.

Comment: You might want to mention that it's not the *only* problem with that comparison.

Comment: Thank you for all your useful tips! I'm starting with c++ and I'm sure I'm going to need every reading that you offer me. I'm going to start studying more and follow your advice! Thank you very much for everything!!